# Batch mixing wav files in sox

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing, sox

i would like to be able to batch mix a bunch of wav files i have in a folder using a bat file with sox..

basically in that folder i have 2 versions of every file, let's say a file named "Brother.wav" and a file named "Brother (2).wav". I would like them both mixed and creating a new "Brother (3).wav" file, and i would need this to happen to every file in the folder, so if i also have a file named "Sister.wav" and a file named "Sister (2).wav" in that folder, it would also work on it to create a "Sister (3).wav" mixed wav file, and so on. The thing is i have no idea what i should write in the bat file for this to work, or even if that is a possibility

What i have so far in my bat file is this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2\sox.exe" -m *.wav *(2).wav  input3.wav
```

which doesn't do what i want, because it takes ALL the .wav in the folder and mix them together to create a single wav file named input3...

I'm sorry as this is probably a very noob issue, and i'm probably not explaining it properly, but i'm not used to using sox and bat files at all and i really need a way to automate that mixing process since i have a ton of files to go through :/

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: You would need to run a `for` loop to do this. Open `cmd` and run `for /?` for usage and syntax examples.

Comment: @Gerhard Thanks for your answer! would you mind providing me with an example code? i've tried what you suggested, but the explanations the cmd give me don't make much sense to me i'm afraid...

Comment: Use the search facility, (at the top of the page), or simply scroll through the most recent questions on the first page, (below your own question), there will be plenty of examples for you to test, and learn from.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
FOR %%e IN ("* (2).wav") DO FOR /f %%y IN ("%%e") DO IF EXIST %%y.wav ECHO "C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2\sox.exe" -m %%y.wav %%e "%%y (3).wav"
```

Note that the `sox` line will simply be `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO "C:\Prog…` to `"C:\Prog…` to actually process the files.

It's a matter of approach. `*.wav` means `ALL .wav files`, hence the results you report.

This solution uses the characteristics of `for` in two ways. Documentation about `for` can be obtained by executing `for /?` from the prompt - or thousands of examples on SO.

First, `FOR %%e IN ("* (2).wav") DO` assigns the name of each file matching `* (2).wav` to `%%e` in turn. The mask is quoted as it contains <kbd>Space</kbd>. (I was impressed that this actually worked! Normally, I'd have used a `dir` command to find filenames) and also because the mask contains `)` (which would close the `for…(` unless quoted or escaped).

So - why use `* (2).wav`? The `(2)` file must exist for the process to be executed, so all we need to do having obtained those names is to find out whether the `*` exists, then assemble the required `sox` command.

Next, `FOR /f %%y IN ("%%e") DO` uses the default `tokens=1` and <kbd>Space</kbd> delimiter to assign the `*` part to `%%y`.

Then we test whether `%%y.wav` exists, and if it does, execute `sox` with parameters constructed from the parts.